# How to add a Splsah screen to React JS website?

Tags: reactjs, splash-screen, visual-web-developer

I am creating a react js website in which i need a splash screen to display for like 5-10 seconds before the homescreen loads like in android apps i want to know how its implmentation would be in react just in general code and app-specification i can do myself

Any Help would be appericated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either make it yourself, with [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) with a mere CSS object using spinner animation,

Or use React's [Lazy](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/lazy#lazy) and Suspense
Check this exemple: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/Suspense#lazy-loading-components-with-suspense